# Javascript in anchor not working with IE

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I'm trying to redirect to my ServletController via an anchor tag and javascript.

Now it works in Google chrome and not in IE. I looked around the web for two days so far and found that IE does not work with setAttribute well with dynamic elements so I had to switch to using the actually attribute and assigning it a value.

The anchor is suppose to create a dynamic form and make a form submission which then creates a new request to my Servlet but for some reason when I click on the anchor in javascript it does nothing. However when I click on the anchor in chrome it does it correctly and redirects me to the next page without any problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Account</title>
<meta name="description" content="eTeam Bank">
<meta name="author" content="Abraham Cabrera">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function anchorRedirect(username, user_id, operation) {
"use strict";
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.name="form";
form.id="form";
form.method = "post";
form.action = "ServletController";

var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField1.type = "hidden";
hiddenField1.name = "username";
hiddenField1.value = username;
form.appendChild(hiddenField1);

var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField2.type = "hidden";
hiddenField2.name = "user_id";
hiddenField2.value = user_id;
form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

var hiddenField3 = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField3.type = "hidden";
hiddenField3.name = "operation";
hiddenField3.value = operation;
form.appendChild(hiddenField3);

form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="title">eTeam Bank</div>
</header>

<div id="container">
    <div class="userTitle" >
        <div class="user">
            Welcome: user
        </div>
        <div class="userTime">
        Thu Jan 31 09:24:16 EST 2013
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accountBox" >
        <div class="accountSpace"></div>
        <div id="accountAnchor">
        <a href="javascript:anchorRedirect('user', '2', 'loadPersonalInfo');">Personal Info</a> 
        </div>
        <div id="accountAnchor"> 
        <a href="javascript: anchorRedirect('user', '2', 'loadAccountInfo')">Account Info</a> 
        </div>
        <div id="accountAnchor"> 
        <a href="javascript: anchorRedirect('user', '2', 'loadAccountSum')">Account Summary</a> 

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div id="footerContent">Abraham Cabrera &copy; 2013</div>
</footer>
```

Additional Details:
1. This is not for any type of production business or corporation and is just for personal studies.
2. I did try passing the variables via the url path directly without using the java script function but that does not meet my requirments because I need to make a new request to my ServletController in order to get the users account information via the model class or which ever operation it was and forward it back to the view.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what is not working. Can you post a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you defining the function before the `<a>` element in the HTML page?

Comment: Edited it to include my error and full code.

Comment: Related: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/10/bug-235-createelement-is-broken-in-ie.html As to the concrete functional requirement, what a terrible piece of code. What's wrong with just plain vanilla links like so `href="servlet?foo=bar"` without the need for all that JS mess?

Comment: If you read my question, maybe a second time you will see that I did use the setAttribute function and yet it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: If you read the link, maybe a second time you will see that the `element.setAttribute("name", name)` works only for **non-IE** browsers (note that `element.name=name` is equivalent). And in future comments please keep the sarcasm for yourself to avoid this self-ridicule.

Comment: Another possible cause is that you didn't add the form to the DOM. This will fail in some browsers as well. Coming back to the ugly JS approach, are you aware that you can do exactly the same in `doGet()` method as you currently do in `doPost()` and use the POST form as an excuse? See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create the form inside the HTML (not via javascript) with all the needed fields inside already. Then, instead of creating and setting the elements, you would radically simplify your JS by simply setting the values of the hidden fields and submitting the form. Something like

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="ServletController">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="">
</form>
```

with a javascript like

```
function anchorRedirect(username, user_id, operation) {
    document.myform.username.value = username;
    document.myform.user_id.value = user_id;
    document.myform.operation.value = operation;
    document.myform.submit();
}
```

Comment: So is there a reason as to why IE doesn't handle the dynamic forms correctly because your solution worked but don't see why mine shouldn't?

Comment: Well... as Charlie points out bellow... it appears the form you are creating is not properly added to the DOM (it kind of floats being part of the document but not in the tree). So... most likely... IE refuses to submit it.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that if I take your code and add a div with id='form_div1' and append the newly created form to it before submit it starts working from FireFox and IE.

```
var my_div = document.getElementById("form_div1");
my_div.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```